# Proving Distributive Law of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be sets. Prove that $A \bigcap (B-C) = (A\bigcap B) - (A\bigcap C)$. Hint: Using 'iff' works on this proof.

This is a question we got in a quiz. The problem is I don't get the hint. I solved it by doing the following:

A = B So we need to show A is a subset of A and B is a subset of A.

Then let x be an element of the LHS. Change the Intersection to 'And' and Union to 'Or'. And so on and so forth. I used this method to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The "hint" is indicating that as you "unpack" the definitions of intersection, set minus, etc, modifying one side of the equation into a different but equivalent form, the steps taken are *bidirectional*: E.g.,$$ \begin{align} x \in \left(A \cap (B-C\right)) &\iff x \in A \text{ and } x \in (B-C) \\ \\ & \iff x\in A \land (x\in B \land x\notin C)\\ \\ &\iff \cdots \\ \\ &\vdots\\ \\ & \iff x \in [(A\cap B) -  (A\cap C)]\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** the hint in the quizz means that you can start your proof with:

$$
\forall x: x\in A\bigcap(B-C) \iff \dots
$$

Comment: Ok so its like this is so iff A iff B iff Answer.

Comment: yep! can you manage it from here?